# Is exclusive type more resource efficient than shared type in Pulsar?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, producer-consumer, pulsar

I found that it will cost lost of memory when using shared type of subscription; So will exclusive mode save more resources?

```
pulsarConsumer, err := pulsarClient.Subscribe(pulsar.ConsumerOptions{
        Topic:                       topicName,
        SubscriptionName:            "test",
        Type:                        pulsar.Shared,
        RetryEnable:                 true,
    })
```